# React/Spring-boot cannot display @ManyToOne relation when some are null

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, jpa, null, entities

I have 3 entities : `project`, `userProject` and `standardProject`, both `userProject` and `standardProject` are a `@ManyToOne` relationship with entity `project`.

I want to display these entities in my Project view, to do so I implemented for both entities the following in my `Project.java` :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "projet", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<UtilisateurProjet> utilisateurs = new HashSet<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "projet")
private Set<StandardProjet> standardProjets = new HashSet<>();
```

And added the `@JoinColumn` in both entities .java files :

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "projet_id")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "utilisateurs", allowSetters = true)
private Projet projet;
```

I display them in my React file. Important point, these relationships can be NULL, sometimes a Project do not have any user or standard related so the following column is empty in my view. However, this is working correctly for `userProject` but not for `standardProject` which throw me :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null
```

When I try to display them.

Any guess ?